# Reversing Exponential Distributions (kind of)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was just wondering how one could go from an exponential distribution to a distribution which describes the probability that a given number of events would happen in the time interval $[0,t]$.   They seem very related, but I cannot find the explicit link between the two.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The exponential distribution is a continuous distribution; it is not the distribution of a number of "events".  Maybe you're confusing the exponential distribution with the  Poisson distribution.  The second half of your first sentence I find incomprehensible.  You want to "go from" the distribution of the number of events in a given amount of time _to_ the distribution of the number of events in time $t$?  What's the difference between the part following "from" and the part following "to"? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The question is what you are varying.  For instance, in the first case I could ask "what is the probability that 3 events happen in 1 hour?   In the second case I could ask "what is the probability that 1 event happens between 3 hours and 4 hours?" or any other time.

Comment: You do appear to be confusing the Poisson distribution with the exponential distribution.  The exponential distribution is the distribution of the waiting time until the next arrival in the Poisson process.  The Poisson distribution is the distribution of the number of arrivals in a specified time.